# Adding component to a JFrame from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am building one really big application. The situation is this:
I have many tables which I can fill with data from my Java app.

I have groups and for each group there is button in my main `JFrame` (Menu) and a table in my database:

**Example:** Table A is storing information for group A

I have one button that is called "New" and it should add new group - so this means to create new table and also to add new button in `MainFrame`. This New Button is opening frame called `NewGroupFrame` for example. Is it possible to add button to my `MainMenu` frame from this `NewGroupFrame`?

**Basically:** Is it possible to add components from one frame to another?

Comment: a component can only belong to one container. You can add it to another, but that will remove it from where it was if it was

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question. I want to create entire new button and to be added to the other frame. I don't want 2 frames to share 1 component.

Comment: `I want to create entire new button and to be added to the other frame.` ok, go ahead and do it. The component doesn't know it will be added to a different frame. All you need is the reference to the panel where you want to add the component. Also, you should not be using a second JFrame. If you need a child window, then you should be using a JDialog. An application will generally only ever have a single parent JFrame.

Comment: Exactly. How to get there? How the reference should look? Also your suggestion of JDialog got my attention. Would you give an example if it is possible.

Comment: Your question contains no code at all, which makes me take a guess: you are using the Netbeans GUI designer till this point and you don't know much at all about actually programming using the Swing API yet. Am I right?

Comment: Absolutely correct

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) The answers provide many alternatives. In this case, it seems a `JTabbedPane` with the content of the new tables as new tabs might be suitable. But there are many options, and you know the situation best. 2) *"How to get there?"* Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov well... that will have to change.

Comment: Thank you all. Not sure how to proceed after reading @AndrewThompson's link and the way I was thinking to proceed is bad.

Comment: "Not sure how to proceed" use the common strategy: break big problem into smaller ones.  First you can add the functionality need functionality to the `JFrame` class. For example `public void addButton(String tableName)` method that allows dynamically adding a button.

Comment: @Gimby Would you give me more information why I should switch NetBeans GUI with Eclipse Swing for example? As per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717889/eclipse-or-netbeans-for-swing-based-application  
it is OK to use NetBeans, even more - it is preferable.